# Nested sequences of balls in a Banach space

Tags: geometry, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces

This seems to be a fairly easy question but I'm looking for new points of view on it and was wondering if anyone might be able to help.

(By the way- this question does come from home-work, but I've already solved and handed it, and I'm posting this out of interest, so no HW tag.)

> Let $B_n=B(x_n,r_n)$ be a sequence of nested closed balls in a Banach space $X$. Prove that $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty B_n\neq\varnothing$.

As I said before, it should be rather simple. When the radii decrease to 0, it's just a matter of selecting any sequence of points in $B_n$, and it must be Cauchy- and the limit is in the intersection.

My question is what to do when the radii do not decrease to 0? I got some tips about multiplying the balls by a sequence of decreasing scalars, or reducing the radii so that they decrease to 0, but found too many pathological cases for both methods.

Finally- I used a geometric arguemnt (which i've shown to work in any normed space) that if $B(x_1,r_1)\subset B(x_2,r_2)$ then $\| x_1-x_2\|\leq|r_1-r_2|$.
This turned out to be some kind of technical catastrophe, but it worked...

Still, if anyone knows of a more elegant solution, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: What's so catastrophic about the geometric argument? All you need is that the affine line spanned by $x_1$ and $x_2$ is isometrically isomorphic to the ground field, then it's just a 1d (or 2d if your space is complex) picture.

Comment: "[...] be a sequence of nested in a banach space". Seems like you missed something there? Should it be "nested closed balls"?

Comment: yeah, it's nested sequence- as the title suggests :) i'm changing it

Comment: It's not true in general. That property is called *spherical completeness* and fails for the p-adic complex numbers, for example.

Comment: ... But that is a complete metric space, rather than a Banach space

Comment: @George: Perhaps the simplest example of a complete metric space where this fails is the natural numbers with the metrc $d(m,n)=1+1/(\min (m,n))$.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't know if this is more elegant, but that's about the best I can come up with at the moment and probably essentially the same as your argument.

---

Consider first the situation $B_{\leq r}(x) \subset B_{\leq s}(y)$. It is easy to see that $r \leq s$.

*Claim.* $\|y - x\| \leq s - r$.

*Proof.* If $x = y$ there is nothing to prove, so let's assume $x \neq y$. The point $z = x - r \frac{y-x}{\|y - x\|}$ belongs to $B_{\leq r}(x)$ and hence also to $B_{\leq s}(y)$. Therefore $\|y - z\| \leq s$. On the other hand,
\[
y - z = y - x + \frac{r}{\|y - x\|} (y - x) = \underbrace{\left(1 + \frac{r}{\|y - x\|}\right)}_{\lambda} (y - x),
\]
so $s \geq \lambda \|y - x\| = \|y - x\| + r$ and hence $\|y - x\| \leq s - r$.

---

This means that a nested sequence of closed balls $B_{\leq r_{n}}(x_{n})$ has the following properties:

1. The sequence $r_{n}$ is monotonically decreasing, hence converges to some $r$.
2. If $N$ is such that $r_{N} \leq r + \varepsilon$ then the above claim implies that for all $n\geq m \geq N$ we have $r_m - r_n \leq \varepsilon$, so $\|x_{m} - x_{n}\| \leq \varepsilon$ because $B_{\leq r_{n}}(x_{n}) \subset B_{\leq r_{m}}(x_{m})$.

In other words, the centers $x_{n}$ form a Cauchy sequence and their limit point $x$ must belong to $\bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} B_{\leq r_{n}}(x_{n})$.

---

**Added:** As Jonas pointed out, the argument can be made even simpler and doesn't need completeness: Suppose $r_{n} \to r \gt 0$. Then there is $N$ such that $r_{N} \leq 2r$. Then for all $n \geq N$ we have $r \leq r_{n} \leq r_{N} \leq 2r$, so $r_{N} - r_{n} \leq r$ and the claim implies that $\|x_{n} - x_{N}\| \leq r \leq r_{n}$, so $x_{N} \in \bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} B_{\leq r_{n}} (x_{n})$.

Comment: @kneidell: While writing this I have forgotten about the fact that you've already had this solution. I don't think there is a much easier way.

Comment: If the limit $r$ of the radii is positive, then $r_N<2r$ for some $N$, and then $x_N$ will be in every subsequent ball (by the claim).

Comment: @Jonas: Right. So you needn't even use completeness in that case. Nice! This hasn't occurred to me before, thanks!

Comment: Did you nowhere use the reflexivity of the Banach space? What about [this example](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201642/cantor-intersection-theorem-exercise)?

Comment: Sorry for this comment which is probably stupid but I am wondering how you would prove that $B_r(x) \subset B_s(x)$ implies $r \le s$. What about these examples:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734248/example-of-two-open-balls-such-that-the-one-with-the-smaller-radius-contains-the ? Thanks.

Comment: @Romeo:Those examples are not normed spaces.  Suppose $B_r(x)\subseteq B_s(y)$.  If $x=y$, then we are saying that $\|x-z\|\leq r$ implies $\|x-z\|\leq s$, and this implies $r\leq s$ (all that is needed for this part are that there are vectors at distance exactly $r$ from $x$, easy to show for any nonzero normed space). If $x\neq y$, then $x+r\frac{x-y}{\|x-y\|}$ is in $B_r(x)$, hence also in $B_s(y)$.  This implies that $\|x-y\|+r\leq s$, so $r<s$.

Comment: @Student: (I know you asked over a year ago, don't know if this is helpful.) Nowhere in the question is the Banach space assumed to be reflexive, nor is it needed.  But the balls in a normed space are special compared to balls in a general metric space.  The answer uses the fact that the metric comes from the norm.

Comment: @Romeo It's trivial that if $E\subset F$ in any metric space then the _diameter_ of $E$ is no larger than the _diameter_ of $F$. Now if we're talking about balls in a normed vector space the radius is half the diameter.