# the sequence of nested balls

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

I need an example of sequesnce of nested closed balls $B_n$(a,r) in complete metric space which has not any common point. The simplest example is desirable because I supposed to show completness as well.

Comment: $(0,1/n)$ (in $[0,1]$).

Comment: sorry, I forgot to say that balls supposed to be closed.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201642/example-of-nested-closed-balls-with-empty-intersection).